# Django Model - Get distinct value list

Tags: database, django, django-models

I try to get a list of distinct foreign keys and I wrote this:

```
my_ids = Entity.objects.values('foreign_key').distinct()
```

But I get just a list of UNDISTINCT foreign keys... What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Passing an argument to distinct doesn't work for MySQL-databases (AFAIK)

This one works and returns just one object:

`Entity.objects.order_by('foreign_key').values('foreign_key').distinct()`

Comment: I have the same issue on a Postgres9.1 database, Django==1.5.5. Adding order_by helped - stupid...

Answer (score 72):

Perhaps you might want to go with this:

```
Entity.objects.order_by().values_list('foreign_key', flat=True).distinct()
```

Comment: WRONG. Wont't work when used without order_by('foregin_key'). E.g on M2M (postgres, django 1.8)

Answer (score 55):

```
Entity.objects.values_list('foreign_key', flat=True).distinct().order_by()
```

`distinct` does not work without `order_by`, [as explained in Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#distinct):

> Any fields used in an `order_by()` call are included in the SQL `SELECT`
> columns. This can sometimes lead to unexpected results when used in
> conjunction with `distinct()`. If you order by fields from a related
> model, those fields will be added to the selected columns and they may
> make otherwise duplicate rows appear to be distinct. Since the extra
> columns don’t appear in the returned results (they are only there to
> support ordering), it sometimes looks like non-distinct results are
> being returned.
>
> Similarly, if you use a `values()` query to restrict the columns
> selected, the columns used in any `order_by()` (or default model
> ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the
> results.
>
> The moral here is that if you are using `distinct()` be careful about
> ordering by related models. Similarly, when using `distinct()` and
> `values()` together, be careful when ordering by fields not in the
> `values()` call.

Comment: O.M.G.! Bonus: that `order_by()` does not order really but solves the distinct problem. This is just insane.

Comment: Does this work? It seems like distinct and order by would require a two column solution with the use of MIN or MAX to get the sorting right.  I'm guessing order by just sorts by the values_list field, which is probably not the default sort order of the model. Proper solution would be to write a custom query:  select value, min(sequence) as sequence from some_table group by value order by sequence;

Comment: `.order_by()` without any args clears any default or existing ordering on the queryset.

Answer (score 9):

```
Entity.objects.order_by('foreign_key').distinct('foreign_key')
```

If you already have them as a list, then convert it to a `set()` to get the distinct values.

Comment: is not this converting to set is a costly idea with respect to memory as with set() everything will be filled in memory where as queryset its not loaded till its evaluated.. and this converting to list thing will evaluate the queryset as well ??

Comment: Sets are unsorted so you'll cancel the order_by, and in some cases that matters.