# django values list get values only once

Tags: django, distinct, django-queryset

I want a list with values from a queryset that only appear once.

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10848809/django-model-get-distinct-value-list) but this does not seem to work for me.

Example:

```
CharacterJournal.objects.order_by("date").values_list("reftypeid", flat=True).distinct()
```

returns something like this:

```
[97, 96, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 97, 42, 42, 42,  52, 42, 42, 1, 42, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']
```

Please help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the note in the documentation on `distinct` [[1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct)]:

> Any fields used in an order_by() call are included in the SQL SELECT columns. This can sometimes lead to unexpected results when used in conjunction with distinct(). If you order by fields from a related model, those fields will be added to the selected columns and they may make otherwise duplicate rows appear to be distinct. Since the extra columns don’t appear in the returned results (they are only there to support ordering), it sometimes looks like non-distinct results are being returned.
>
> Similarly, if you use a values() query to restrict the columns selected, the columns used in any order_by() (or default model ordering) will still be involved and may affect uniqueness of the results.

In other words, because you're ordering by `date`, the query returns pairs of `(date, reftypeid)` and the `DISTINCT` clause is performed on this pair. The `date` is later dropped because of `values_list`, but there is no additional removal of duplicated `reftypeid` entries.

Comment: Is there a way around it? since my class meta already orders the list. (of coarse i can uset set(returned_list) just thought there would be a django way to do this

Comment: Just call `order_by()` with no parameters to clear the ordering.